# Cannot install google-cloud-videointelligence package

Tags: python, pip, video-intelligence-api

I'm trying to install Google Cloud's Video Intelligence library for Python.
However, when I run the command:

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-videointelligence
```

I get the following error:

```
(video_labeler) PS C:\path> pip install google-cloud-videointelligence
Collecting google-cloud-videointelligence
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/32/4518904fb73fa8264c6e827df6c062e3c62b0a6dc7eb34a35b7e60d3ed93/google_cloud_videointelligence-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0 in c:\path\lib\site-packages (from google-cloud-videointelligence) (1.14.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in c:\path\lib\site-packages (from google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0->google-cloud-videointelligence) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.4.0 in c:\path\lib\site-packages (from google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0->google-cloud-videointelligence) (3.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0 in c:\path\lib\site-packages (from google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0->google-cloud-videointelligence) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\path\lib\site-packages (from google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0->google-cloud-videointelligence) (2019.3)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=34.0.0 in c:\path\lib\site-packages (from google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0->google-cloud-videointelligence) (40.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: googleapis-common-protos<2.0dev,>=1.6.0 in c:\path\lib\site-packages (from google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0->google-cloud-videointelligence) (1.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth<2.0dev,>=0.4.0 in c:\path\lib\site-packages (from google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0->google-cloud-videointelligence) (1.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio<2.0dev,>=1.8.2; extra == "grpc" in c:\path\lib\site-packages (from google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0->google-cloud-videointelligence) (1.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\path\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0->google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0->google-cloud-videointelligence) (1.25.6)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\path\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0->google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0->google-cloud-videointelligence) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\path\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0->google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0->google-cloud-videointelligence) (2019.9.11)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\path\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0->google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0->google-cloud-videointelligence) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in c:\path\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2.0dev,>=0.4.0->google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0->google-cloud-videointelligence) (0.2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools>=2.0.0 in c:\path\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2.0dev,>=0.4.0->google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0->google-cloud-videointelligence) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa>=3.1.4 in c:\path\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2.0dev,>=0.4.0->google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0->google-cloud-videointelligence) (4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6 in c:\path\lib\site-packages (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth<2.0dev,>=0.4.0->google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0->google-cloud-videointelligence) (0.4.7)
Installing collected packages: google-cloud-videointelligence
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\path\\Lib\\site-packages\\google\\cloud\\videointelligence_v1p1beta1\\gapic\\transports\\__pycache__\\video_intelligence_service_grpc_transport.cpython-37.pyc'
```

This is being run in a virtualenv based on Python 3.7.

Help to fixing this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is this issue resolved when new venv is created

Comment: @ArunJose_Intel It's behaving kinda weird. The package installs fine outside of a venv, but fails inside one. As this was merely for debugging purposes I can live with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try installing in a virtualenv

Mac/Linux

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv <your-env>
source <your-env>/bin/activate
<your-env>/bin/pip install google-cloud-videointelligence
```

Windows

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv <your-env>
<your-env>\Scripts\activate
<your-env>\Scripts\pip.exe install google-cloud-videointelligence
```

Comment: I am already running this in a virtualenv based on Python 3.7. I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: can you try creating a new venv and try again